# Rails - Passing an option variable in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a header partial for a view. I call the partial as following:

```
<%= render :partial =>"project/header", :locals => {:right_header => 'BLAH BLAH'} %>
```

The header has a default right_header, but I'd like the option to overwrite it:

```
<div id="header">
<span class="right">
 Standard Header here
</span>
</div>
```

The deal is when calling the partial, right_header won't always be defined, I'd like for it to be optional, but that's where I'm struggling and rails keeps erroring... In the partial I've been trying:

```
<% if right_header.empty? %>
 default header....
<% else %>
 <%= right_header %>
<% end %>
```

Suggestions? Am I passing this correctly to the partial with locals?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
if defined? right_header
```

another way is

```
right_header ||= 'default'
```

in the view.  so if `right_header` is not passed in, its value will be `default`.  You can pass in any value too, and later on just do things according to the value of `right_header`.

Comment: Thanks! is the locals a good way to pass an html block to a partial?

Comment: SHOOT... It's rendering the HTML tag I'm passing as: &lt;a href=&quot;&quot;&gt;